# VLOOKUP in Excel with IF statements?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm not sure whether `IF` statements are actually needed in this problem;
however, I'm totally stumped.

In the first worksheet I have a column for "years employed" (Column D6:D107) ranging from 0.1 to 4.9.

I had to create a table in a second worksheet with this information:

> 'Lookup Tables'!E2:F5

```
Range for Years Employed             Sick Days
Less than 1 year                         0
At least 1 year but less than 2 years    1
At least 2 years but less than 3 years   1.5
At least 4 years or more                 3.5
```

I am required to use a `VLOOKUP` function to return the answer for how many sick days each person gets and I am totally stumped on how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you entered the vlookup formula in a cell with some test values and seen what it returned?

Comment: “At least 4 years or more” is redundant.  It’s good enough to say either “At least 4 years” or “4 years or more”.  (See also teylyn’s remark about the gap between 3 and 4.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a gap in the logic. What is the number for 3 years? It is not covered in the description.

In any case, create a table with "years employed" in the first column and the allowance in the second column. Make sure the table is sorted ascending by the first column. Then you can use a vlookup with the "true" parameter. Let's say this table starts in A1.

```
years employed  allowance
0               0
1               1
2               1.5
4               3.5
```

Then you can use a vlookup like

```
=VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$B$5,2,TRUE)
```